# How to custom colour a network chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a directed force chart and I wanted to add custom colour how would I go about saying if the label = US or Russia I wanted them to be coloured blue and red, else I want everything else to be the same colour this is my code for my nodes, I created separate variables for US and Russia but I'm unsure what I'm supposed to do next:

```
const usa = nodes.filter(d => d.label == "UNITED STATES")
    console.log(usa)
const russia = nodes.filter(d => d.label == "RUSSIA")

const node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 1)
    .attr("fill", "#F2D974")
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.4)
simulation.on("tick", () => {
  link
      .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
  node
      .attr("cx", d => d.x)
      .attr("cy", d => d.y)
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the condition to the fill attr, for example:

```
const node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 1)
    .attr("fill", (d) => d.label === 'UNITED STATE' ? 'blue' : (d.label === 'RUSSIA' ? 'red' : "#F2D974"))
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.4)
```